# Creating a DAX table that takes unique values based on the lowest date?

Tags: powerbi, dax

(Dates are in Euro format DD/MM/YYYY)

The table on the left (call it `TableA`) is the data in the beginning. It includes the name of 5 people, the history of their certification levels, and the date in which a check on their current certificate was made.

The table on the right (call it `TableB`) is the result I would like to achieve in a new DAX table. The rows where a new check was made on a person **but no change on their certification level was made**, are filtered out.

So for instance, a check on Bob's certification was made on 3/2/2023 (row 2), then a new check was made 20/3/2023 (row 3). However because his certification remains the same (no changes), then row 3 is filtered out and only the initial check at 3/2/2023 where Bob had the certification A-2 is inlucded.

I have tried using a combination of `TableB = DISTINCT(SELECTCOLUMNS(TableA, "Name", TableA[Name], "Certificate-Level", TableA[Certificate-Level]))` however I can't seem to include the date column due to multiple values, so I need to find another approach.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like:

```
Table B = 
SUMMARIZE ( 
    'TableA', 
    'TableA'[Name],
    'TableA'[Certificate-Level],
    "Date of Check" , CALCULATE ( MIN ( 'TableA'[Date Of Check] ) )
)
```

`SUMMARIZE` over a table will return a new table with the distinct combinations of the specified table columns. It also allows adding own columns with custom expressions that can access the underlying row context as long as you use `CALCULATE` (or use a pre-defined measure) in the expression to force context transition.

However, persisting this table in addition to `TableA` is probably not best practice. While this answers your question, perhaps this question is not the correct one, see [XY-Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).